# How to add multiple validations in asp.net in c#

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to validate the age of the person and the field should be mandatory to fill.Moreover the range should be 2-3 digits.One validation alone is working but the data is also getting stored which i dont want to.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" value="number" runat ="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2"
ControlToValidate="txtAge"
MinimumValue="18"
MaximumValue="80"
Type="INTEGER"
EnableClientScript="false"
Text="The date must be between 18 and 80!"
runat="server" />
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: so what is the issue? use two validators. RequiredFieldValidator and RangeValidator.

Comment: No Its not working for me.Moreover the incorrect data is also getting stored in database.

Comment: "range should be 2-3 digits" but your error message is "must be between 18 and 80". So what is correct?

Comment: Its age should be 18-80 but digits should me 2-3

Comment: 18-80 range can b represented only using 2 digits.. you can use validation group property to group more than one validation.

Comment: that i have to define beforehand.Like if a user enter 6 in age that should alo be validated

Comment: I don't understand why you need to validate if the user enters two or three digits. Why does that matter if the value is already between 18 and 80?

Comment: and what about if the validation is true ,how can i stop the data being entered in the data base

Comment: and what about the required field validation thing.How can i write that also

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatorAge" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="Age must be between 1 & 100"
MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="100"
ControlToValidate="txtAge" Type="Integer"
ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RangeValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorAge"
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Age is required"
ControlToValidate="txtAge" ForeColor="Red"
Display="Dynamic" >
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: HEy Ayoub its not working for me.I need some code or group validation kind of thing since using more than two validation is giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to disable client-validation, therefore you have used `EnableClientScript="false"`. Ok, but then you have to force validation on serverside via `Page.Validate()`:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // save your data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ValidationGroup`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" value="number" runat ="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="ag"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2"
ControlToValidate="txtAge"
MinimumValue="18"
MaximumValue="80"
Type="INTEGER"
EnableClientScript="false"
Text="The date must be between 18 and 80!"
runat="server" ValidationGroup="ag" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorAge"
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Age is required"
ControlToValidate="txtAge" ForeColor="Red"
Display="Dynamic"  ValidationGroup="ag">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```